# Haskell type declaration explaining the fold?

Tags: haskell

I am new to the Haskell and currently studying about fold and unfold and their type declarations. I am struggling to understand what this type declaration means:

```
foldT :: (u -> u -> u) -> (a -> u) -> Tree a -> u
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Give a guess.   How many arguments does it take?  What do you think each argument means?  What do you think the type variables `u` and `a` represent?

Comment: `Tree a` has two constructors, having some types (which ones?). `u->u->u` and `a->u` are two functions, having related types to the constructor types. This is not a coincidence.

Comment: I am sorry English isn't my first language and I don't do guessing. As far as I can tell `(u -> u -> u)` is for the tree but I am unsure on what the `(a -> u)` bit means

Comment: When analyzing type signatures, think about what they **are** not what they **are for**. For example, what is `(u -> u -> u)`? Because of the `->` this just looks like a function, right? Also, it has nothing to do with `Tree a` because the type variables `a` and `u` are different.

Comment: p.s. You should answer try to the questions in luqui's comment.

Comment: `(u -> u -> u)` corresponds to the tree's branch and `(a -> u)` corresponds to the tip, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! So, the first function argument specifies "what to do" on branches, and the second function argument "what to do" on tips, roughly. Try to define the fold by induction on the tree argument, and you'll see there's only one reasonable way to make everything fit together.

Comment: @chi Sorry I can't understand exactly what you mean by "define the fold by induction on the tree argument", could you please explain that?

Comment: @Mina, it just means to define `foldT` by pattern matching on the constructors of the tree, possibly using `foldT` recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to break it up into small parts.

In pseudo-Haskell, the signature is

```
foldT :: some-function-x -> some-function-y -> Tree a -> u
```

and the name is `foldT`, therefore probably something "summarizing" all of the tree in a single result. It's also safe to guess that `Tree a` indicates a tree whose nodes' values are of type `a`.

So `foldT` takes `some-function-x`, `some-function-y`, a `Tree a`, and summarizes the `Tree a` by a  `u`.

How would we go about summarizing a tree? Presumably, we could recurse down to each leaf, and summarize each `a` value we encounter by a `u`. Backtracking in the recursion, an internal node now sees only `u` value in its descendants (and possibly itself), and it must summarize them to a single `u`.

Indeed, `some-function-x` has the type `(u -> u -> u)`, that is, a function used by internal nodes to summarize two `u` values, and `some-function-y` has the type `(a -> u)`, that is a function summarizing a node value by a `u` value.

---

**Example**

Suppose `a` is `String`, and so the tree is a tree of `String`s. Furthermore, the purpose of the fold is to "summarize" the tree by calculating the total length of the strings stored in it. Then

- `u` could be `Int`

  - `some-function-y` could be [`length`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=length) - it summarizes individual strings.
  - `some-function-x` could be `(+)` - it summarizes two summaries into a single one.